# Save edit from editable wx.ListCtrl - wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there a way of saving the edit you make when you double-click on a cell in a variable or to a file? I want to be able to edit the cell and update my database (a .txt file). Take the code I found from [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/) as an example of an editable listctrl:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

########################################################################
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    ''' TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited. '''

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, row[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, row[3])
            index += 1

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Editable List Control")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT: Printed output for solution provided by Rolf of Saxony:

```
Ford Taurus 1996 Blue
Changed Item:  Column: 3

Entire listctrl BEFORE the update:
Ford Taurus 1996 Blue
Nissan 370Z 2010 Green
Porche 911 2009 Red

Entire listctrl AFTER the update:
Ford Taurus 1996 
Nissan 370Z 2010 Green
Porche 911 2009 Red

Data for export
Ford Taurus 1996 
Nissan 370Z 2010 Green
Porche 911 2009 Red
```

As you can see, if I try and edit it like you did, nothing is shown.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this with wxpython Phoenix? The reason for asking is that I have hit exactly the same issue when trying to port one of my projects onto wxpython 4.0.0b2. My original answer works a treat on wxpython prior to Phoenix, now nothing comes back, no text and no label.

Comment: No, I am sorry. I didn't :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to know how to access the data within the `listctrl` rather than write to a file.
The editable listctrl is a sneaky beast, in that what you see after the edit is not actually in the data until you update it (with `self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem()`.
The method is to bind to `wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT` and perform an update of the listctrl item that was altered.
This example, hopefully shows you how to access the changed item, access the entire listctrl, perform the update, access the entire (updated) listctrl and finally create exportable data.

The print and output occurs after every edit. In reality, you would perform the export of the data either on exit or via the click of a button for example, not after every edit.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

########################################################################
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    ''' TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited. '''

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, row[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, row[3])
            index += 1
        self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnUpdate)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnUpdate(self, event):
        row_id = event.GetIndex() #Get the current row
        col_id = event.GetColumn () #Get the current column
        new_data = event.GetLabel() #Get the changed data
        cols = self.list_ctrl.GetColumnCount() #Get the total number of columns
        rows = self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount() #Get the total number of rows

        #Get the changed item use the row_id and iterate over the columns
        print (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row_id, colu_id).GetText() for colu_id in range(cols)]))
        print "Changed Item:", new_data, "Column:", col_id

        #Get the entire listctrl iterate over the rows and the columns within each row
        print "\nEntire listctrl BEFORE the update:"
        for row in range(rows):
            row_data = (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
            print row_data

        #Set the new data in the listctrl
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(row_id,col_id,new_data)

        print "\nEntire listctrl AFTER the update:"
        #Create a list that can be used to export data to a file
        data_for_export=[]
        for row in range(rows):
            row_data = (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
            print row_data
            data_for_export.append(row_data) #Add to the exportable data

        print "\nData for export"
        for row in data_for_export: #Print the data
            print row

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Editable List Control")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Edit:
Printed result of changing Ford Taurus 1996 Blue to Ford Taurus 1996 Green

```
Ford Taurus 1996 Blue
Changed Item: Green Column: 3

Entire listctrl BEFORE the update:
Ford Taurus 1996 Blue
Nissan 370Z 2010 Green
Porche 911 2009 Red

Entire listctrl AFTER the update:
Ford Taurus 1996 Green
Nissan 370Z 2010 Green
Porche 911 2009 Red

Data for export
Ford Taurus 1996 Green
Nissan 370Z 2010 Green
Porche 911 2009 Red
```

On Linux OS, wxpython '2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode)'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why do you iterate over the columns?: `for colu_id in range(cols)]))`

Comment: Also, it seems to just erase the data within in the cell I change and the 'new' data doesn't come up. When printing it that is.

Comment: is it supposed to do this?

Comment: The reason for iterating over the columns, is to build a string, with `join` that represents the entire row (all 4 columns). As to your other queries, you will have to be more explicit, as I don't understand what your issue is. What prints out is 1: the entire row that changed, the changed data and the column number 2: the entire list as it was before the update 3: the entire list after the update. Note the reference to "sneaky beast".

Comment: Well, if I decide to change "Blue", it will display when printing BEFORE UPDATE, but AFTER UPDATE it won't display. It will say Ford Taurus 1996 and leave the 4th item blank. It won't appear in the 'data to export' part. It doesn't seem like `new_data = event.GetLabel()` works. :/

Comment: 1. Are you using the same OS and wx version as stated at the bottom of my answer? 2, Try adding `print "item", event.GetItem().GetText()` after the `new_data = event.GetLabel()` line and see what you get.

Comment: I'm running 3.0.3 and Windows 10. Anyway, it prints "item" (of course) and nothing else is changed. I try printing `event.GetItem().GetText()` and it prints a blank line. :/

Comment: Having had a look at the reference manuals 2.8 and 3.n, it appears that `listctrl.SetStringItem()` has vanished, to be replaced by `listctrl.SetItem (self, index, column, label, imageId=-1)`, so all I can suggest is that you try `self.list_ctrl.SetItem(row_id,col_id,new_data)` and see if that updates the data in the listctrl. It does not work on wx 2.8 but it may work for you on wx 3.0.3

Comment: Hmm alright, thanks for your help. :) It doesn't work but as you're experienced with a different version and I'm a complete newbie at 3.0.3, it's clear that this isn't going to work. I will try and implement version 2.8.12.1 and try this again. :)